# Have icon appear in the middle perfectly

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the image appear in the middle of the text... Right now the icon is a little bit higher.

I tried using:

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

But it made it appear lower then the text. Is there any way to make it appear in the middle without using `margin` or `padding`

**HTML:**

```
<div class="text">Text: </div>
<div id="icon"><img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/35i3ltu.png" height="30" width="30" /></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.text{
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #6699ff;
    font-size:2.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: avenir;
}
#icon{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fnvgrq0v/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/16xa5a2g/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/fnvgrq0v/2/)

this should work it goes in line with the text if you have letters like `y` which goes below then you will see it has aligned vertically

eg i have shown in the fiddle with `y`

```
#icon {
    display:inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

you can also add image inside the div and adding `vertical-align:middle` will align it

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/fnvgrq0v/5/)